# Unable to pass property name dynamically to ListView.ItemTemplate to bind (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a user control like this

```
<UserControl
x:Class="App41.UserCntrl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <ListView SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="lview"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"  >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind PropertyNameToBind, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

code behind

```
    public sealed partial class UserCntrl : UserControl
{
    public UserCntrl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(UserControl),
         new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public string PropertyNameToBind
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PropertyNameToBindProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropertyNameToBindProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyNameToBindProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyNameToBind", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

And I am calling this user control in my main page like this

```
<Page
x:Class="App41.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App41"  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <local:UserCntrl x:Name="lview"   Loaded="EditTextControl_Loaded"></local:UserCntrl>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EditTextControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<OptionItem> io = new ObservableCollection<OptionItem>();

        io.Add(new OptionItem { Name = "11111111111" });
        lview.ItemsSource = io;
        lview.PropertyNameToBind = "Name";
    }
}

public class OptionItem 
{
    private string _Name = string.Empty;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value;  }
    }
}
```

All looks good to me, but ListView displays empty items instead of my content. I believe the issue is in this line

```
  <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind PropertyNameToBind, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Where I am trying to bing `Name` property inside the `OptionItem` Model. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, each `DataTemplate` corresponds to an item in the `ItemsSource`, so the `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` is limited to the item itself, specific to your project, is `OptionItem`.

You use `{x:Bind PropertyNameToBind}` is actually trying to bind `OptionItem.PropertyNameToBind`, but your `OptionItem` does not have this property, so nothing will be displayed.

Please determine whether you want to bind `PropertyNameToBind` or `OptionItem.Name` property, if it is `OptionItem.Name`, please use `{x:Bind Name}`.

If not, try this:

```xml
<UserControl
    ...
    x:Name="Main">

    <Grid>
        <ListView SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="lview"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Main,Path=PropertyNameToBind}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

**Update**

I think I understand what you mean, but you have some misunderstandings about binding.

What you bind is a property, and you pass a string value. This value cannot be used as a property name to reflect the properties of the binding class.

Combined with your needs, I recommend that you use the interface for dynamic processing:

**interface**

```cs
public interface ITest
{
    string GetDisplayText();
}
```

**class**

```cs
public class OptionItem : ITest
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string GetDisplayText()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

**control**

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ITest">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind GetDisplayText()}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

By creating an interface, a method for outputting displayed text is provided.

Any class that inherits this interface can override this method according to their needs.

Inside the control, you only need to call the `GetDisplayText()` method, regardless of which class is bound.

Comment: I want PropertyNameToBind  itself to be bound. And I tried your solution, I am still getting empty ListView

Comment: Hello, please limit the type of your `ItemsSource`, such as `IEnumerable<OptionItem>`. If the problem persists, you can provide the target version and minimum version of your application. I tested normally on the 1909 device. If you can tell why you want to do this binding instead of binding the properties in `OptionItem`, it would be more helpful. Do you want to modify the UI synchronously when you change the properties in `OptionItem`?

Comment: I won't be able to change the ItemsSource type, This user control needs to be used across an entire project, and on different scenarios, we will need different types of IEnumerable to be bound. It won't be always OptionItem.

Comment: here you can find the details you asked, with my entire code
https://filebin.net/t73bczrj2h51cifi

Comment: I don't want to bind the OptionItem directly, As this will be a generic user control which will be used across the project, with different types of IEnumerable as ItemSource

Comment: Hello, in the code in my answer, I named the `UserControl` **Main**, you seem to be missing this

Comment: yes, Sorry I missed it, Corrected now. But now Listview displays "Name" instead of "this is a text" . Means it displays the exact string I am passing as "PropertyNameToBind " instead of the value of it

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Grid>
        <ListView SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="lview"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemSource, Mode=OneWay}"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind OptionItem.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I can't hard code OptionItem.Name inside user control, value whatever will be bound will be dynamic and will come from the page user control is called

Comment: I'm not following what you're attempting to do here. You have different pages that all have a Listview control on them. These controls need to Bind to a collection on the page and then display the items? Does the collection always contain the same type of objects? Is the collection name always the same?

Comment: there is a user control that contains a listview. This user control will be used on various pages. On each page, I need to assign different ItmesSource to this listview. Each ItemsSource will be of a different type, But all will be an IEnumerable.

Comment: In each page, I will assign an Itemsource and a PropertyNameToBind. ItemsSource contains an Ienumberable with multiple fields And PropertyNameToBind string will decide out of those fields which one need to be bound to the listview